# laravel sanctum SPA authentication Protected routes return { "message" : "unauthenticated"}

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, oauth

I am working on a big project that has a laravel backend for API and a separate SPA (vue-cli scaffolded).
they are found on the same top level domain the laravel project runs at the domain(m.m) and the Vue Spa runs at(vue.m.m:8080)

what my problem is:

- auth:sanctum protected routes does not work they return ({ "message" : "Unauthenticated" })

what works:

- route /api/login works perfectly when given the correct password and email (it sends a response ({"message" : "Login successful"}))

my code snippets:

.env (it is only the part that is needed based on the docs I cant show the other because of security issues)

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=.m.m
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=vue.m.m
```

### backend

UserController => for Authenticating

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return response()->json(['user'=> $user,
                                  'message'=> 'registration successful'
                                ], 200);
    }
      /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Login successful'], 200);
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged Out'], 200);
    }
}
```

sactum.php

```
<?php

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
    )),
    'expiration' => null,
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, 
    ],

];
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable,HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return "protected route";
});

Route::post("/login","App\Http\Controllers\UserController@login");
```

cors.php (for development purposes I allowed all incoming requests to be processed) and (credentials are set to true)

```
'paths' => ['*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

 'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

### Frontend

axios

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://m.m/api';
```

Vue (this is the method that handles sending login requests)

```
login(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
        axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie", { baseURL: "http://m.m" }).then(() => {
          axios
            .post(
              "/login",
              { email: "john@doe.com", password: "password" },
            )
            .then(() => {
              const res = axios.get("/user");
              console.log(res.data);
            });
        });
      };
    }
```

what I get from the browser
[network tab from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTUOr.png)

this is what is stored in the browser as cookies
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuNJJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved as the following:

In the api routes define

```
Route::get('/unauthenticated', function () {
    return response()->json(["message" : "unauthenticated"]);
})->name('api.unauthenticated');
```

Now in the method `redirectTo` in the `Authenticate.php` middleware add this line

```
if ($request->is('api/*') || $request->is('api'))
 return route('api.unauthenticated');
```

And that's it.
It works for me